# Stratified Intercept in Individual Patient Data Metanalysis in R

Tags: r, regression, random-effects-model, meta-analysis

I am trying to run an Individual Patient Metanalysis (IPD) in R.
However, using a Random Intercept Model seems not to be appropriate since I only use 4 Trials.

In this [article](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-017-0307-7) a stratified study intercept is proposed like this:
[image]

In a random effects model I would have fitted the model like this:

```
lmer(outcome ~ treatment + baseline + (1 + treatment | trial), data = data)
```

Can anyone help me get my head around implementing the stratified intercept instead of the random-effects model? I understand that the idea is to fit a model for every trial and use the trial-specific intercept, but I don't understand how to get it all together in the end.